# Synchronizing java FX with Java Swing

Tags: swing, javafx-2

How could i synchronize the UI developed in JavaFX with Java swing application?

I designed my UI in javaFX and rest of the program done in java Swing .

Now I want to synchronize both.
Otherwise how can i develop my project using javaFX instead of using java swing?

please anyone help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from here

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm

now my problem solved.